# How to determine which Eclipse feature provides a specific jar file

Tags: eclipse

I am the happy user of a Terminal view in my work and home instances of Eclipse Oxygen.2. According to the process manager on my Windows 10 system, the terminal is in this path:

```
D:\Programs\Eclipse Oxygen\plugins\org.eclipse.cdt.core.win32.x86_64_5.4.1.201709131603\os\win32\x86_64\winpty-agent.exe
```

Given that I haven't installed the CDT feature, I am guessing that one of my installed features drew this plugin in.

I would like to benefit from direct integration of a terminal in my other Eclipse instances so I can build some of my projects from within Eclipse, instead of switching to a different window.

More generally, is it possible to determine which feature provides a specific plugin? Other than by uninstalling features one by one until the terminal view is no longer available.

EDIT:
These are some tabs in Eclipse Installation Details.

[image: Installed Software tab]

I can see plugins related to the terminal:
[image: Plug-ins tab, filtered by "terminal" keyword]

But none of these providers can be seen in the Features tab (excerpt, sorted by provider):

[image: Features tab]

Answer (score 1):

It is **TM Terminal** that provides this feature. This can be installed to eclipse from the market place:
http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/tm-terminal

Comment: Great. It is indeed that terminal. Unfortunately, I don't see "TM Terminal" anywhere in the Eclipse Installation Details window: I am still looking for the Eclipse equivalent of `mvn dependency:tree`, `yum whatprovides` or `yarn why`, i.e. a way to tie a plug-in to its requiring feature. In my case, the terminal seems to come with TypeScript IDE, which shows up in the Installed Software tab but has no features at all in Features tab. I had to dig through feature.xml files and file timestamps, without being positive about the link between TS IDE and the terminal view.

Comment: TM expands to "Target Management". I could see the feature entries in the Features tab under the provider 'Eclipse.org - Target Management' as 'Terminal Control' and 'Terminal View Core'. Also 'TM Terminal' is listed under the 'Installed Software' tab. Isn't that in your case?

Comment: Indeed, I saw the meaning of "TM" on the CDT project pages. I've added some screenshots to the question. The missing link to me was and is that the providers I see in the Plug-ins tab are missing from the Features tab.